# Why isn't it filter(not None, iterable)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Since the definition of `filter()` is to return a list of elements in which the function returns `True`, wouldn't `filter(not None, iterable)` make more sense for filtering to a list that only includes items that aren't `NoneType`?

Comment: Consider via plain-old order of operations that `not None` evaluates to `True`, so you're really evaluating `filter(True, iterable)`. Understandably, this results in the error `'bool' object is not callable`.

Comment: what's wrong with `filter(lambda x: x, iterable)`?

Comment: And, FWIW, you don't need `filter`:  `(x for x in iterable if x is not None)`

Comment: It's not "functions [that] return `True`" (note uppercase and fixed-width font) but rather "functions that return true".  That is, `filter` is defined loosely as `def filter(fn, iterable): result=[]; for i in iterable: if fn(i): result.append(i)`.  We're concerned with "truthiness", i.e., what `bool(fn(i))` would say.

Comment: @muratgu: `filter(lambda x: x, iterable)` is the same as `filter(None, iterable)` and discards empty strings, instances whose `__bool__` returns `False`, and so on.  `filter(None, ['a', '', 'c'])` => `['a', 'c']` but `filter(lambda x: x is not None, ['a', '', 'c'])` => `['a', '', 'c']`.  (NB: these are Python2 examples; Python3 `filter` produces a `<filter object ...>`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Since the definition of `filter()` is to return a list of elements in
>   which the **function** returns True

But `not None` is a not function, and so not callable. `None` is used as shorthand for the identity predicate (not just function), which in this case can be `lambda x: bool(x)` or simply `bool`. So instead of what you propose, you would do:

```
filter(lambda x: x is not None, iterable)
```

More so, the `None` shorthand is a generalization that applies to some other builtin functions in python: `map`, `itertools.ifilter`, `itertools.imap`, `itertools.ifilterfalse` among others.

A pythonic equivalent of `filter` (an iterator version from the docs) will look:

```
def filter(predicate, iterable):
    # filter(lambda x: x%2, range(10)) --> 1 3 5 7 9
    if predicate is None:
        predicate = bool # evaluates truth value of the object
    for x in iterable:
        if predicate(x):
            yield x
```

Comment: Just seems a little counterintuitive - couldn't it just as easily be `filter(lambda x: x is True, iterable)`? May I know what other built-in functions to which you are referring?

Comment: But with `filter(lambda x: x is True, iterable)`, a lot of things could easily go wrong:  `'cafeKaze' is True -> False`. A more *easy* generalization would be `filter(bool, iterable)`.

Comment: Koledoy wouldn't `filter(lambda x: x is not None, iterable)` also be incorrect in that case then? `0 is not None -> False`

Comment: I suggested that as a replacement for your proposal, and not as a generic form. Remember, the `None` form is only a shorthand.

Answer (score 6):

For *python3* you don't need to use a lambda, `None.__ne__` will only filter *None*:

```
In [1]: list(filter(None.__ne__, [None, 0, 1, 2]))
Out[1]: [0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 5):

[Quoting from the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)

> If function is None, the identity function is assumed, that is, all elements of iterable that are false are removed.

In other words, passing `None` in the fist parameter is a special case. All false-y values are removed.

This doesn't however mean what you said. In general `filter` expects a callable. `not None` is **NOT** a callable. It is on its own just `True`  You'd use:

```
lambda x: x is not None
```

Answer (score 4):

`not None` is just `True`. The correct syntax for what you're thinking of would be

```
filter(lambda x: x is not None, iterable)
```

That would work for what you're trying to do, but it's not actually what `filter(None, iterable)` does.

`filter(None, iterable)` is a special case. When `filter` sees a filter predicate of `None`, it replaces that with the identity predicate, `lambda x: x`. It filters out any object in the iterable that's considered false in a boolean context. That means that

```
filter(None, [None, 0, 1, 2])
```

filters out both `None` and `0`, not just `None`.

Comment: Also filters out `''`, correct? Does `lambda x: x` mean something on its own - not sure I understand. Still, if we're talking about truthy values, wouldn't it make more sense if it was `filter(True, iterable)`?

Comment: No, because `True` isn't a function, it is a boolean literal. It doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: @cafeKaze: It would also filter out `''`. `lambda x: x` is a function that just returns its argument. As for `filter(True, ...)`, the idea was that `None` is "no function", not that we're filtering out things that look like `None`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Eh, the special case for `None` doesn't make much more sense. I doubt that special case would exist if `filter` had been introduced later in Python's development.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I meant `filter(True, iterable)` as shorthand for `filter(lambda x: x is True, iterable)` - feels more intuitive to me at least.

Comment: @cafeKaze: It feels more intuitive to you, but not that one guy who liked functional programming and submitted the patch that added `filter` way back in something like the early 90s.

Comment: (`lambda x: x is True` doesn't produce the current behavior either, but if we're going to talk about hypothetical other ways to design `filter`'s weird special case, there's no need to restrict ourselves to its current behavior.)

Answer (score 1):

It is, kind of, you just need to turn it into a function

```
filter(lambda x: x is not None, iterable)
```